# javascript Y scroll-bar moving on mouse of downbutton but the window goes horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a portfolio side similar to this one. Only a little bit more a beginners version. But with the same concept.

www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/

Is the anyone who know how I can scroll sideways where the y scroll-bar is used?

And I have another question ? where can I read about those skills and/or practice?

Comment: Have you checked out the source code? (http://www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/script/main.js)

Comment: you can trigger the event of scroll and then find the scroll points, then do some math and apply the same to horizontal scroll, something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He basically uses a `onscroll` event handler in which he detects the y value (scrollHeight) and sets/moves/displays/hides/etc objects on specific y values. The page is just scrolling down, but the elements are moved in. So it looks like horizontal scrolling, but it's not. It's elements moving from right to left, etc.

(A lot of (very fine!) work by the author.) Have a closer look at:

```
window.onscroll = function (e)
{
    if (canScrollOrSwipe == true) //to avoid user swipe when window is still resizing after screen orientation changed on table
    {
        detectPageVerticalPosition();
        runTheseFunctionsAfterScrollOrSwipe();
    }
}
```

And the functions called there.

**Or better yet**: contact this webdesigner himself before copying :)